# Is it possible to access the ctx context in @beforeSave Adonis 5?

Tags: adonis.js

How could I do something like that?

```
@beforeSave()
public static async audit(model: Model) {
  console.log(ctx.auth.user)  
  await Audit.create({
   model,
   ctx.auth.user
  })
}
```